# what package manager can I use to install cockpit-machine on ubuntu server?

Tags: debian-installer, cockpit

I have tried to install cockpit-machine on ubuntu server using dnf package manager. I got feedback 'sudo: dnf: command not found'

Comment: There is no package called `cockpit-machine` in the Ubuntu repositories. It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish...or why you are trying to accomplish it using the wrong package manager for Ubuntu.

Comment: The OP has done no research. I just Googled it  you need to install the KVM environment first. https://www.tecmint.com/install-kvm-on-ubuntu/  Then you can install the app he was sort of trying to install. https://www.tecmint.com/manage-kvm-virtual-machines-using-cockpit-web-console/

Answer (score 0):

DNF is the Fedora Project package manager, however in Ubuntu the default package manager is apt. To install Cockpit user interface for virtual machines in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install cockpit-machines
```